# Use oauth2-client with codeigniter class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0, composer-php

I am trying to use the oauth2-client from [oauth2-client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client).

I installed the package via composer and it created a vendor folder in my root with the league package in. 
I then copied it to my application/third_party/vendor folder.

In my controller I am trying to do this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class APl extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Force SSL
        $this->force_ssl();

        // Form and URL helpers always loaded (just for convenience)
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');

        //Load Libraries
        $this->load->library('managers/NameManager');
        $this->load->library('managers/BreadcrumbManager');
    }

    public function aPLogin() {
        $provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
            'clientId'                => 'demoapp',    // The client ID assigned to you by the provider
            'clientSecret'            => 'demopass',   // The client password assigned to you by the provider
            'redirectUri'             => 'http://example.com/your-redirect-url/',
            'urlAuthorize'            => 'http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/authorize',
            'urlAccessToken'          => 'http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/token',
            'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/resource'
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my config file I tried putting this code:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
require FCPATH . 'third_party\vendor\autoload.php';
```

and in my index.php file looks like this:

```
require FCPATH . 'third_party\vendor\autoload.php';

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

I tried changing the FCPATH require by:

```
require_once APPPATH.'third_party\vendor\autoload.php';
```

Also tried:

```
include_once BASEPATH.'../application/third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then I am either getting:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\third_party\vendor\autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\index.php on line 311
```

or

```
Message: Class 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider' not found
```

Comment: Your main problem is that CodeIgniter expects your vendor directory to be inside the application directory. That's where your composer.json file belongs, and where you'll run your composer commands to install/update packages.

Comment: @BrianGottier thank you for your answer, my directory structure looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/BPhnU

Comment: That's exactly why it's not working. The vendor directory must be be at the same level as third_party. AND codeigniter will automatically run autoload.php, so you don't have to do that yourself.

Comment: @BrianGottier I moved the vendor folder outside of third_party so it looks like this now: https://imgur.com/a/XcDRl

Now in my config do I only need $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE; and in my index.php, do I need something in there as well?

Comment: All you should need is `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;` . You need to have your composer.json file at the same level as `/vendor/` and `/third_party/`. Once you've done that, run composer install and/or update, because composer will need to update the paths to all your packages.

Comment: My file structure is as follows: https://imgur.com/a/xBKnO 
Then in my config.php it says: $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE; and in my index.php i removed the code for require_once APPPATH.'vendor\autoload.php';

still the class not found error

i did try the composer update and composer install

Comment: Seems like it should work, but I'm not in a position to try it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wanted to show you what it took for me to use the package you are trying to use. I set up a fresh install of CodeIgniter, then did the following...

**First, I set composer autoloading in config/config:**

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

**Next, a minimal composer.json, located at APPPATH:**

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "league/oauth2-client": "2.2.1"
    }
}
```

**From the command line:**

```
cd /path/to/application
composer install
```

**Then, in my welcome controller I put this:**

```
public function oauth_test()
{
    $provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
        'clientId'                => 'demoapp',    // The client ID assigned to you by the provider
        'clientSecret'            => 'demopass',   // The client password assigned to you by the provider
        'redirectUri'             => 'http://example.com/your-redirect-url/',
        'urlAuthorize'            => 'http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/authorize',
        'urlAccessToken'          => 'http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/token',
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/resource'
    ]);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $provider );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

**When I go to /welcome/oauth_test in my browser, I get this:**

```
object(League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider)#15 (17) {
  ["urlAuthorize":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  string(51) "http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/authorize"
  ["urlAccessToken":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  string(47) "http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/token"
  ["urlResourceOwnerDetails":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  string(50) "http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/resource"
  ["accessTokenMethod":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["accessTokenResourceOwnerId":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["scopes":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["scopeSeparator":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["responseError":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  string(5) "error"
  ["responseCode":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["responseResourceOwnerId":"League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider":private]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["clientId":protected]=>
  string(7) "demoapp"
  ["clientSecret":protected]=>
  string(8) "demopass"
  ["redirectUri":protected]=>
  string(37) "http://example.com/your-redirect-url/"
  ["state":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["grantFactory":protected]=>
  object(League\OAuth2\Client\Grant\GrantFactory)#16 (1) {
    ["registry":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["requestFactory":protected]=>
  object(League\OAuth2\Client\Tool\RequestFactory)#17 (0) {
  }
  ["httpClient":protected]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Client)#18 (1) {
    ["config":"GuzzleHttp\Client":private]=>
    array(7) {
      ["handler"]=>
      object(GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack)#19 (3) {
        ["handler":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=>
        object(Closure)#26 (2) {
          ["static"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["default"]=>
            object(Closure)#24 (2) {
              ["static"]=>
              array(2) {
                ["default"]=>
                object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler)#20 (5) {
                  ["factory":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=>
                  object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)#21 (2) {
                    ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=>
                    array(0) {
                    }
                    ["maxHandles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=>
                    int(50)
                  }
                  ["selectTimeout":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=>
                  int(1)
                  ["active":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=>
                  NULL
                  ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=>
                  array(0) {
                  }
                  ["delays":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=>
                  array(0) {
                  }
                }
                ["sync"]=>
                object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler)#22 (1) {
                  ["factory":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler":private]=>
                  object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)#23 (2) {
                    ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=>
                    array(0) {
                    }
                    ["maxHandles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=>
                    int(3)
                  }
                }
              }
              ["parameter"]=>
              array(2) {
                ["$request"]=>
                string(10) ""
                ["$options"]=>
                string(10) ""
              }
            }
            ["streaming"]=>
            object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler)#25 (1) {
              ["lastHeaders":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler":private]=>
              array(0) {
              }
            }
          }
          ["parameter"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["$request"]=>
            string(10) ""
            ["$options"]=>
            string(10) ""
          }
        }
        ["stack":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=>
        array(4) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            object(Closure)#27 (1) {
              ["parameter"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["$handler"]=>
                string(10) ""
              }
            }
            [1]=>
            string(11) "http_errors"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            object(Closure)#28 (1) {
              ["parameter"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["$handler"]=>
                string(10) ""
              }
            }
            [1]=>
            string(15) "allow_redirects"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            object(Closure)#29 (1) {
              ["parameter"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["$handler"]=>
                string(10) ""
              }
            }
            [1]=>
            string(7) "cookies"
          }
          [3]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            object(Closure)#30 (1) {
              ["parameter"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["$handler"]=>
                string(10) ""
              }
            }
            [1]=>
            string(12) "prepare_body"
          }
        }
        ["cached":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["allow_redirects"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["max"]=>
        int(5)
        ["protocols"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(4) "http"
          [1]=>
          string(5) "https"
        }
        ["strict"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["referer"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["track_redirects"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
      ["http_errors"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["decode_content"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["verify"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["cookies"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["headers"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["User-Agent"]=>
        string(56) "GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.47.0 PHP/7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, anything you're doing beyond that is not necessary. If it were me, I guess I'd try to remove the entire vendor directory and try again. Also, I notice you are on Windows, and while I don't think that should matter, I am on Linux (which is the production environment for most web code).

Comment: This worked for me! I am not sure what I was doing wrong before but this did the trick. Thank you very much!